# I am writing a code to upload a document to a specific folder in sharepoint document library using web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I am creating a web api to upload the document in a specific folder in a sharepoint document library. I know how to it using csom in a console application.

The dlls which I am using in web api for sharepoint csom code are :-
1. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Portable
2. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Portable
3. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Windows

Dlls which is used for uploading documents in a console app are :-

1. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
2. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime

Csom code for console application :-

```
using (var filestream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        context.Load(list.RootFolder);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                        var fileinfo = new FileInfo(filename);
                        var result = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                        var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}/", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, caseno);
                        //Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File newfile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl + result);
                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl + result, filestream, true);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
```

This is working fine in console application.

Same code if I am trying in with a web api it gives an error that "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File" doesn't contain a method name 'SaveBinaryDirect'.

Can anyone please help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: `SaveBinaryDirect` belongs to the assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

Comment: Yeah but I am using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.portable.dll which doesn't contain this method.

Comment: Why don't you add a reference to that assembly?

Comment: SaveBinaryDirectisn't included in the assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.portable.dll. i am using latest version of it. Still it havent been included in this dll.

Comment: Again, you can still add a reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll along with other DLLs

Comment: Can only use either Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.portable.dll or Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll